# Which Coding standard support by wordpress? like psr-0 or something else

Tags: wordpress

I want to know which coding supported by the WordPress like

> psr-0,psr-1

or others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the psr version. But this article has all official standards.

Also according to the WordPress coding standards, PSR-4 and the PSRs for coding style, such as PSR-2 are wrong. A simple example is class naming.

https://torquemag.io/2018/01/dont-follow-wordpress-coding-standards/
https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/#language-specific-standards